# GetAxis("Vertical")

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use `GetAxis` to get the value from the vertical axis of the player in my game. My goal here is for my code to see if the player is under `.6 y`, aka anything under `.6` for his position to be changed back to the spawn point.

This is my code right here, Spawn is referred to a gameobject in Unity.

```
if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") < 0.6) {
    transform.position = Spawn[0].position;
}
```

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the bad formatting on my question, I'm just trying to figure out how to reset my players value if the vertical axis' value is under 0.6. Thank you!

Comment: You cannot use vertical axis to compare with transform.position.y because they are completely different  , axis values are between -1 to 1 , and transforms are real world positions , use the answer given by Neven

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you exactly mean by axis, but if you mean position is game you can use:

```
if (transform.position.y < 0.6f) {
   transform.position = Spawn[0].position;
}
```

Comment: No problem, please mark my answer if it helped you.